# Get content of value attribute with javascript and css selectors

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I would like to extract the $18.99 in this code with Javascript and CSS Selectors. Is this possible.  If so, how?

```
<input type="hidden" name="priceBefore" value="$18.99" />
```

Comment: what code? can you post it?

Comment: so select the element and read the input's value, what is hard about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use css selectors with `Document.querySelector()`.

Documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.querySelector('[name=priceBefore]');

  if (input) {
    document.body.innerHTML += input.value;
  }

};
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="priceBefore" value="$18.99" />
```

Comment: probably better to get it by name, not use `document.write` and execute it after DOM has loaded.

Comment: @Pamblam. Thanks for the tip. ill change it

Comment: the `querySelector` call is what should be in `window.onload`, but you really should probably just put the whole thing in the onload call just to be safe..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
document.getElementsByName("priceBefore")[0].getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: does not use css selectors

Comment: The item in question has a name set. Seems a little redundant to query it by css selector.

Comment: who cares what it seems like, that was the question.

Comment: note that this wil include the "$" in the value - will need to be removed if you want to do calculations. also the value will be a string so will need to be converted to a number using parseFloat() which will allow the decimal point and decimal places